# Correctly formatting date string for iCalender file via DateTime class?

Tags: php, icalendar

An iCalender file expects the `DTSTART` and `DTEND` parameters in its file to be of the format:

```
20140715T035959Z
```

Basically, long form year, double digit month, double digit day, the letter 'T' to break the date from the time, then double digit hour, minute, second, etc. appended with the letter 'Z'.

I currently have a date in the following PHP format:

```
Y-m-d H:i:s
```

I'm currently trying to format it with the `DateTime::format` method into an iCalender accepted string, and I thought this might work:

```
format('Ymd\THis\Z');
```

I've escaped the characters T and Z in the hopes they would appear, but when my event is echoed into the file, it's simply empty. I have a feeling my representation of the iCal datetime format is incorrect. Ideas?

**Current iCal code:**

```
DTSTART:".$calData->eventStart()."
```

**Current `$calData->eventStart()` code:**

```
public function eventStart() {
    $inputDateTime = $this->details['date_time'];

    // Convert MySQL datetime to ical datetime
    $temp = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $inputDateTime);
    $eventStart = $temp->format('Ymd\THis\Z');

    echo $eventStart; // This should be RETURN, not ECHO! 
}
```

---

### ANSWER:

Yeah, so it turns out this was a non-question. I was simply `echoing` the datetime instead of `returning` it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like this...

```
<?php
$pubDt='20140715T035959Z';
$pubDt=str_replace(array('T','Z'),array('',''),$pubDt);   
$format = 'Ymdhis';
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $pubDt);
echo $newPubdate = $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');  //"prints" 2014-07-15 03:59:59
```

Comment: You've got the code the wrong way around. I'm going from PHP to iCal, not from iCal to PHP. :)

Comment: What is wrong with `$temp->format('Ymd\TGis\Z');` ? You are doing it right.

Comment: I guess you should change your `echo $eventStart;` to `return $eventStart;`